# Creating JObject with JObject.FromObject ignores DateFormatString

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to create a Newtonsoft JObject with a custom DateFormatSting ("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") using JOjbect.FromObject and I think there is a bug.  My code is:

```
JObject jBytes = JObject.FromObject(myObject, MyJsonSerializer);
```

Here, JObject.FromObject seems to ignore the DateFormatString in my custom JsonSerializer.

I have a workaround, but still curious if I am doing something wrong, or if anyone else has seen this?

(workaround)

```
JObject jBytes = Object.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject, MyDateFormatString);
```

Comment: Could you add your `MyJsonSerializer` code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this is that `JValue` stores the `DateTime` *as an actual `DateTime` structure copied from your object*, not as a string.  Therefore the `DateFormatString` is not applied during the conversion to `JToken` hierarchy.  You can verify this by doing the following:

```
        var types = jBytes.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JValue>().Where(v => v.Type == JTokenType.Date).Select(v => v.Value.GetType().FullName);
        Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(types, Formatting.None));
```

The output will be `["System.DateTime", ...]`.

Thus the setting needs to be applied when you convert your `JToken` to its ultimate JSON string representation.  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a convenient `ToString()` overload on `JToken` allowing a `DateFormatString` to be specified.  One possibility would be to serialize the root token:

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatString = "yyyy/MM/dd" };

        var jBytes = JObject.FromObject(myObject);

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jBytes, Formatting.Indented, settings); // Outputs "2015/09/24"
```

This at least avoids the parsing overhead of `JToken.Parse()` in your workaround.

Another option would be introduce an extension method modeled on [`JToken.ToString()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs) and the [`TraceJsonWriter` constructor](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/TraceJsonWriter.cs) that takes a `JsonSerializerSettings` and applies the appropriate settings:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static string ToString(this JToken token, Formatting formatting = Formatting.Indented, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        using (var sw = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
            {
                jsonWriter.Formatting = formatting;
                jsonWriter.Culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                if (settings != null)
                {
                    jsonWriter.DateFormatHandling = settings.DateFormatHandling;
                    jsonWriter.DateFormatString = settings.DateFormatString;
                    jsonWriter.DateTimeZoneHandling = settings.DateTimeZoneHandling;
                    jsonWriter.FloatFormatHandling = settings.FloatFormatHandling;
                    jsonWriter.StringEscapeHandling = settings.StringEscapeHandling;
                }
                token.WriteTo(jsonWriter);
            }
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatString = "yyyy/MM/dd" };
        var json = jBytes.ToString(Formatting.Indented, settings); // Outputs "2015/09/24"
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BJOVsR).